# How to debug underlying C++ library from Python interface?

Tags: python, c++, gdb, caffe, pdb

I am using [apollocaffe](https://github.com/Russell91/apollocaffe) and [Reinspect](https://github.com/Russell91/ReInspect). Apollocaffe is in c++ library and Reinspect is in python. Reinspect called apis from apollocaffe.
I like to debug those apis inside apollocaffe. From python code, I used

```
python -m pdb train.py
```

But I can't go inside api from apollocaffe.
I do like `cout << "test" << endl; in apollocaffe`. But nothing is printed to console. How can I debug c++ code, at least if I can print, it will be great.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are interested to debug just the C++ part, you can just start GDB with Python -

```
gdb python
b <C++ function to break at>
run train.py
```

Of course you need to compile Caffe with debug information: pass -DDEBUG=1 to cmake options of uncomment the `DEBUG = 1` line in your Makefile.config.
Debugging both Python and C++ from gdb might be more complicated, see [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb) for example.

Comment: Have you tried the standard cout / printf? These should work.

Comment: does the C++ library that you are using contain the debug flag?

Comment: @SheikhFaisalMiskhat You're right, thanks. Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @SheikhFaisalMiskhat yes in the makefile.config,  DEBUG := 1 is uncommented.

Comment: @rursw1 yes I used cout. but doesn't print to console

Comment: @batuman: Maybe the cout is inserted to an incorrect place? Maybe there are several versions of the library and you're linking to the wrong one?

Comment: @rursw1 yes I am checking now.